# Do I have to declare a constant to import my module data from a scraped file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Looking to import my scraper file data `scraper.rb` into the application.

Can't understand why I am getting this error, or why I must declare a constant called `SCRAPER` as the error suggested.

> Puma caught this error: expected file /Users/jmwofford/Desktop/Dev/scratchpad/scratch2_PRIMARY/projects/rails_scraper/scraperProj/app/controllers/scraper.rb to define constant Scraper, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)

Below given is my code

**scraper.rb**

```rb
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'json'
require "awesome_print"
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
require 'mechanize'

module ScraperFinder
    def scrape_essential_data
        uri = URI.parse("https://buildout.com/plugins/4b4283d94258de190a1a5163c34c456f6b1294a2/inventory")
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
        request.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        request["Authority"] = "buildout.com"
        request["Accept"] = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        request["X-Newrelic-Id"] = "Vg4GU1RRGwIJUVJUAwY="
        request["Dnt"] = "1"
        request["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
        request["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"
        request["Origin"] = "https://buildout.com"
        request["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "same-origin"
        request["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors"
        request["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty"
        request["Referer"] = "https://buildout.com/plugins/4b4283d94258de190a1a5163c34c456f6b1294a2/leasespaces.jll.com/inventory/?pluginId=0&iframe=true&embedded=true&cacheSearch=true&=undefined"
        request["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        
        req_options = {
            use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
        }
        
        response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
            http.request(request)
        end
        
        json = JSON.parse(response.body)
        
        props = json['inventory']
        
        props.each do |listing|
            
            property = {
                'id' => listing['id'],
                'name' => listing['name'],
                'address' => listing['address_one_line'],
                'description' => listing['id'],
                'property_type' => listing['property_sub_type_name'],
                'attr' => listing['index_attributes'],
                'latitude'=> listing['latitude'],
                'longitude' => listing['longitude'],
                'picture' => listing['photo_url'],
                'sizing' => listing['size_summary'],
                'link' => listing['show_link'],
                'brokerContacts' => listing['broker_contacts']
            }
            
            Property.create(
                name: property.name,
                address: property.address,
                description: property.description,
                property_type: property.property_type,
                lat: property.latitude,
                lon: property.longitude,
                pic: property.picture,
                size: property.sizing,
                link: property.link,
                brokerContact: property.brokerContacts
            )
            p "==========================================================================================="
            # pp property
        end
    end 
end
```

**Users Controller**

```rb
require_relative ("./scraper.rb")
include ScraperFinder
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @scraped = ScraperFinder.scrape_essential_data
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <% @scraped.each do |s|%>
           <div class="prop_container"> <%= s %>  </div>   
        <%end%>
        
        <script src="" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Schemas**

```rb
create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "property_type"
    t.string "attr"
    t.string "lat"
    t.string "lon"
    t.string "pic"
    t.string "size"
    t.string "link"
    t.string "brokerContact"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Comment: Can you try moving this file to `lib/scraper.rb` and then `require Rails.root.join "lib", "scraper.rb"`

Comment: That seemed to do something, but now I am getting an error, saying
```NoMethodError (undefined method `name=' for #<Class:0x00007fd2a5421128>)```
and it points to the creation block of code ..

Comment: Sometimes fixing one error reveals another error. Spend a bit of time reading the error and look at which line it's originating from. Eventually you'll come to recognize errors and can instantly know how to fix them. You haven't shared that information so it's hard to me to tell you anything useful there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk) (the autoloader used in Rails 6+) assumes that you declare constants in a file with the same name as the constant. `scraper.rb` is thus expected to declare the constant `Scraper`. Zeitwerk unlike the old autoloader will walk your autoloading directories at startup and index all the files which is why it complains even if you haven't referenced the constant `Scraper`.

You can configure Zeitwerk to ignore certain folders but you really should just get with the program and adjust your code to the autoloader. Start by renaming your file `scraper_finder.rb` and it does not belong in the controller directory since its not a controller. Place it in `app/lib` or `app/clients` or anywhere really is more suitable.

This is really only the tip of the iceberg through as this code is quite broken. What you actually want is something like:

```
# app/lib/scraper_finder.rb
require 'net/http'
# You don't need to require gems as they are required by bundler during startup

module ScraperFinder
  # You need to use self to make the method callable as `ScraperFinder.scrape_essential_data`
  def self.scrape_essential_data
    req_options = {
      use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
    }
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(
        self.get("https://buildout.com/plugins/4b4283d94258de190a1a5163c34c456f6b1294a2/inventory")
      )
    end
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    json['inventory'].map do |listing|
      Property.create(extract_attributes(listing))
    end
  end 
  
  private

  def self.extract_attributes(listing)
    listing.slice('id', 'name').symbolize_keys.merge(
      description:    listing['id'],
      property_type:  listing['property_sub_type_name'],
      attr:           listing['index_attributes'],
      lat:            listing['latitude'],
      lon:            listing['longitude'],
      pic:            listing['photo_url'],
      size:           listing['size_summary'],
      link:           listing['show_link'],
      brokerContacts: listing['broker_contacts']
    )
  end
  
  def self.get(uri)
    Net::HTTP::Get.new(URI.parse(uri)).then do |req|
      req.content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      req["Authority"] = "buildout.com"
      req["Accept"] = "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
      req["X-Newrelic-Id"] = "Vg4GU1RRGwIJUVJUAwY="
      req["Dnt"] = "1"
      req["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
      req["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"
      req["Origin"] = "https://buildout.com"
      req["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "same-origin"
      req["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "cors"
      req["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "empty"
      req["Referer"] = "https://buildout.com/plugins/4b4283d94258de190a1a5163c34c456f6b1294a2/leasespaces.jll.com/inventory/?pluginId=0&iframe=true&embedded=true&cacheSearch=true&=undefined"
      req["Accept-Language"] = "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    end
  end
end
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @scraped = ScraperFinder.scrape_essential_data
  end
end
```

Hashes in Ruby are not like objects in Javascript or a Struct so your code will raise a NoMethodError on `property.name` - to access hash properties use square brackets `property['name']`. But as you can see all that duplication was never warranted in the first place as Ruby has excellent hash manipulation methods.

Your method was also declared as an instance method yet you are calling it as  `ScraperFinder.scrape_essential_data`. To make it a module method you need to use `def self.scrape_essential_data`.

Some quick refactoring also splits that unwieldy monster into three separate methods that are easier to read an reason about.

You don't need to manually require your own code if its in the app directory and doing so will just introduce bugs. Use the autoloader.

`include ScraperFinder` is copying all the methods from your module into the global scope since you are calling it outside of a module/class! Since your module just appears to have singleton methods (methods called on the module itself) you don't need to be importing it anywhere.

Comment: @eyeslandic thanks! At least I didn't call it Zeitgeist this time.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr: Yes, for Rails 6 autoloading to work you need to define a class or module which matches the filename.

- Put the file in the appropriate app directory. Yours goes into `app/controllers`.
- Because it is a module, and Rails calls them "concerns", it should be in the `concerns` subdirectory.
- The rest of the file path must match the class or module name. `ScraperFinder` goes in `scraper_finder.rb`.

So the module ScraperFinder which extends Controllers goes into `app/controllers/concerns/scraper_finder.rb`.

If it were `Scraper::Finder` that would go into `app/controllers/concerns/scraper/finder.rb`.

Rails doesn't care exactly which `app` subdirectory it goes into, or whether it's in a `concerns` subdirectory or not. But it is good for organization.

Then you do not need to require the file, Rails will autoload for you.

---

[Rails will autoload files for you](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). You don't have to put `require app/model/foo` to use the `Foo` model. You just use `Foo` and Rails will go load the appropriate file for you.

[Rail 6 introduced a new and improved autoloading system called Zeitwerk](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#autoloading). In Rails 5 it would determine the filename from the constant. Now it will determine the constant from the filename.

For example, in Rails 5 if you tried to use `Scraper` it would go and look for `scraper.rb` somewhere in `app`. This could lead to strange results.

In Rails 6, Rails will scan the files in app and assume they are constants. If it sees `app/controllers/scraper.rb` it assumes that is the file for `Scraper` and will [register `Scraper` to be autoloaded](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-autoload): `autoload('Scraper', 'app/controllers/scraper.rb')`. When `Scraper` is first mentioned Ruby will do the equivalent of `require 'app/controllers/scraper.rb'`. It also requires that once the file is loaded `Scraper` is defined.

`autoload` is a normal Ruby method, so we can see this in action.

```
# test.rb
p "Hello"

# in irb

> autoload("Test", "./test.rb")
> Test
"Hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/schwern/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/schwern/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/schwern/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):4
NameError (uninitialized constant Test)
```

Using `Test` loads `test.rb`, but because it did not define the `Test` class we get a NameError.

---

Note that you're using ScraperFinder incorrectly. It needs to be included inside the class for it to inject its methods.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include ScraperFinder

    def index
        @scraped = ScraperFinder.scrape_essential_data
    end
end
```

But then you're using it as a class, not a module. A module injects its methods and you'd use them directly.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include ScraperFinder

  def index
    @scraped = scrape_essential_data
  end
end
```

But this is better done as a class. These are not included, they're just used normally.

This type of class which accesses a service is a [Service class](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) and should go into `app/services`. Rails will autoload all the immediate subdirectories under `app`.

```
# You don't need to require external libraries
# if they are defined in your Gemfile.

# app/services/scraper_finder.rb
class ScraperFinder
  def self.scrape_essential_data
    ...
  end
end

# app/controller/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      # ScraperFinder will be autoloaded   
      @scraped = ScraperFinder.scrape_essential_data
    end
end
```

Comment: Good answer. I didn't really want to go down the service objects rabbit hole and just salvaged the code instead.

Comment: @max And I didn't want to get into the code details. They are good, complimentary answers.